# Timer freezes on scroll in Android 7 Webview Ionic App

Tags: android, ionic-framework, webview, timer, android-7.0-nougat

I have a Ionic1 App and I use an ion-timer on one view, below it on the same view is a ion-scroll element with a list of items.

**Example Code:**

```
<ion-content scroll="false">
  <ion-timer class="timer" duration="duration" ispause="isPause" opts="ionTimerOpts""></ion-timer>
  <ion-scroll>
    //list content here...
  </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

The Timer gets refreshed with an $interval and counts down a variable.

On Android 7 Google changed the Webview to Chrome and with that I encountered a strange bug. When the user scrolls through the list, the timer freezes for a few seconds before it counts down again. This does not happen on every scroll but very often, so I guess it has something to do with system resource management. On older Android systems and on iOS this freeze does not occur.

So I'm looking for help to find a solution. I thought I may change the Timer to calculate the distance to a set timeStamp, in this way the timer stays correct in time, but the ui freeze would still be there, and that should not be the case.

**EDIT:**

It seems, that the chrome browser engine sets the priority of intervals very low, thats why intervals are not accurate enough for a timer, my solution was to change the timer code in a way that I simulate an interval with an recursive function that uses timeouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that the chrome browser engine sets the priority of intervals very low, thats why intervals are not accurate enough for a timer, my solution was to change the timer code in a way that I simulate an interval with an recursive function that uses timeouts.